# How to make global cached function in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I need to use below code in a lot of route of my laravel 5 application so first: how to make it a simple function? second: how to cache result of this query for at least 10 minutes

```
$devices = \Auth::user()->devices()->whereNumber($number)->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your first question ,you could add another method to your `User` class like this -

```
public function MyFuncName($number){
    return $this->devices()->whereNumber($number)->firstOrFail();
}
```

if you want it to be cached for each user you could do it like this in Laravel 4 -

```
public function MyFuncName($number){
    return $this->devices()->whereNumber($number)->remember(10)->firstOrFail();
}
```

But in Laravel 5 you should do this like this:

```
public function myFuncName($number){
    return \Cache::remember('user_device_' . $number, 10, function() use ($number)
    {
        return $this->devices()->whereNumber($number)->firstOrFail();
    });
}
```

To call the function you would do

```
$devices = \Auth::user()->MyFuncName($number)
```

Forgot to mention that you must verify the user before as if \Auth::user() return null/false [user is not authenticated] then it will throw you an exception that this method doesnt exist

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work on Laravel 5, it seems remember() is missing in laravel 5 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-remember-missing-from-query-builder?page=1

Comment: Sorry,havent use the cache driver with database yet though it was still there,anyway edited my answer for L5